Сохранение базы данных пользователю Android
Пишу приложение на Android на движке Godot.
Сейчас у меня есть следующий код, с помощью которого я копирую базу данных из ресурсов приложения на устройство пользователя
var data_path = "res://scripts"
var db_path = "res://scripts/data.db"
var copy_path = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/data.db"

func copy_base():
    var dir = DirAccess.open(data_path_new)
    if !dir.file_exists("C:/Users/user/Desktop/data.db"):
        dir.copy(db_path, copy_path)

На компьютере все работает отлично, если базы данных нет, она создается, если есть - все дальнейшие изменения происходят в ней. Пытаюсь прописать путь copy_path на Android, но все варианты, что пробую не работают.
Пробовала следующие варианты:
/data/data/*название_приложения*/data.db
/Android/data/*название_приложения*/data.db
storage/emulated/0/Android/data/*название_приложения*/data.db

Возможно, глобально делаю что-то не так, потому что это первое мое приложение на андроид

Но зачем это всё, если в Godot есть user://? https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/io/data_paths.html#accessing-persistent-user-data-user

Не получается, и просто "user://data.db" пробую и в другие папки, но не копируется база

Почему вы решили что не копируется и что происходит вместо копирования?

Вариант "user://data.db" работает на компьютере, но на андроиде нет. Если база есть, то информация из нее отображается на экране

Не отображаться может по десяткам разных причин, как вы определили, что проблема именно в копировании?

Наверняка не знаю, просто предположение, что если бы скопировалась, то и отображалась бы. Если прав каких-то не хватает или директория выбрана неверно, то опять же не копируется

А давайте не предполагать, а отладчик в руки и выяснять что конкретно происходит в каждой строке кода https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/debug/overview_of_debugging_tools.html#deploy-with-remote-debug

user:// и на компьютере работает по каким-то причинам не так.
При его использовании условие if !dir.file_exists("user://data.db"): не срабатывает даже если база уже создана, обновляется при каждом запуске

А зачем тут DirAccess вообще, если есть FileAccess (ну и показанный вами код неполный, так что я не знаю что за дичь вы творите в непоказанных частях)
